# No such file or directory: Anaconda Error, python CSV file reader

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to learn how to manipulate CSV files in python 3.x and I'm using Anaconda's Spyder IDE to do it When I execute the code I get " No such file or directory exists".

I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda to make sure I have it added to my PATH. I have also tried moving the CSV around to other files to see if it can locate it but nothing.

```
import csv
with open('bar.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
 reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')   
 for row in reader:
    print(', '.join(row))
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bar.csv'

Comment: You need to provide the fully path of the file @WillArmentrout check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Find the full path of file via by joining folder and file name via [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and use that path when opening the file.

```
import os

#Find full path by joining folder and file name
csv_path = os.path.join('<csv_folder>','bar.csv')
with open(csv_path, newline='') as csvfile:
    #do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Place you `.csv` file in the working directory i.e. at the place where your python file is located. It will work.